# why stack() doesn't create accessor in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, svg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1J5a.png)

```
var layers = d3.stack()
                        .keys(keys)
                        (payment);
                        
                console.log("layer",layers);
```

from this code i get layer console like this it return y0 value as 0 , y1 value as NaN [added in above image].

var keys = ["Cash", "Credit card", "Debit card", "Bank Transfer", "Online Payment", "TDS Payment", "Payment gateway", "Cheque"];
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dmc0.png)

My original data from response is payment from above image i add that response .
any one help me  out find a mistake .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Data should be manipulate before executing stacked area chart , i made a mistake in data manipulate that's why I didn't get accessor .